# Rank of product of matrices (analytic proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$A$ is (nxn) full-rank matrix. $B$ is (nxm) matrix with rank k. I want to prove analytically that $$rk(AB) = k$$

I am not sure if my answer is correct or not, but here it is:

As vector space spanned by $B$’s columns is $k$-dimensional, we can express any $k$-dimensional vector (e.g. $s$) as a linear combination of columns of B:

$$s=Bx$$ with  $s$ -> (nx1); $B$ -> (nxm); $x$ -> (mx1)

$x$ here is a (mx1) vector of coefficients of the linear combination. By notation $s$ is (nx1) vector, but it is only k-dimensional (only k entries are non-zero), as this vector is the linear combination of $B$’s columns, from which only $k$ columns are linearly independent from each other.

As matrix $A$ is (nxn) and full-rank, it hast n linearly independent columns. Then if we multiply $A$ by vector $s$, then $As$ will be a linear combination of only $k$ (out of n) linearly independent columns of $A$, as (n-k) entries of vector $s$ are zero.

Now again any k-dimensional vector can be represented by $As$.

$$As = A(Bx) = (AB)x$$

By that we prove that vector spaces generated by columns of $AB$ and by columns of $B$ arethe same. Subsequently, their dimensions are the same and that is the definition of rank, so

$$rk(B) = k = rk(AB)$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now.

Comment: I think your mistake is really "...but it is only $k$-dimensional (only $k$ entries are non-zero)...". This isn't the right condition: instead, arbitrary $s \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are representable in the way you specify if and only if $s \in \operatorname{im}B$. Now, you are right that $\operatorname{im}B$ is $k$-dimensional, but this does not mean that it consists of vectors with only $k$ entries nonzero.

Comment: In general $\operatorname{im}B$ simply has a basis consisting of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which could for example all happen to have all nonzero entries. (Recall for example that the standard basis vectors for all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ all have only one nonzero entry!)

Comment: (Here the image $\operatorname{im}B$ is the same thing as the range of $B$. Sorry, my comment had a very confusing typo so I have reposted it.)

Answer (score 1):

> As vector space spanned by B’s columns is k-dimensional, we can express any k-dimensional vector (e.g. s) as a linear combination of columns of B:
>
> s=Bx

This statement doesn't make any sense. The columns of $B$ are in $R^n$. The columns span a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. It doesn't make any sense to represent a "k-dimensional vector" in terms of vectors in $R^n$.